# C pointers (arrays) memory allocation (hexadecimal)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory

I was playing with memory addressing in C and I encountered a situation I cannot fully explain.

EDIT: the code is compiled by a c++ compiler. (g++)

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
int main()
{

    int* array[10]; //array of pointers to integers

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            array[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
            *(array[i]) = i;
        }


    printf("\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
       {
            printf("%d:%p\n", *(array[i]), array[i]);
       }
    printf("\n");




    int arr[10]; //array of integers

    int* start = arr; //pointer to the first element (array decay)
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        arr[i] = i;

    printf("\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("%d:%p\n", *(start + i), start + i);
   }
   printf("\n");

 return 0;
 }
```

Everything compile and works however I get strange memory addresses.
For the first array I get something like:

```
0:0x23e4010
1:0x23e4030 (32 bits between the addresses which is correct)
```

but for the second array I get:

```
0:0x7ffdaf876290
1:0x7ffdaf876294 (only 4 bits? or maybe they are bytes - but why the long addresses???)
```

Can someone explain this? (also is there a function to transform the hex into decimal without any effort?)

Comment: It's not clear why you expect what you expect. Therefore it's difficult to explain it, because for us it's not "weird" the way it is for you. Regardless, I have attempted to answer.

Comment: BTW please fix your question's title: it does not stand out one bit.

Comment: Also, those ``%p`` print memory addresses, which are bytes not bits. So the first two are 32 bytes apart and the second two are 4 bytes apart.

Comment: Patrick Roberts your comment makes sense. But I get all of them at 32 bytes difference (maybe that's how my platform allocates them).

Comment: Yes, that's what everyone's point is. All of this is platform dependent and you should not expect or depend on any particular behavior since it should never directly concern you if you write your programs safely and correctly.

Comment: OK then this solves it. I had the impression that the addresses are in bits - thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first instance, your array is an array of pointers. Each element is a pointer and, when you allocate memory for each pointer to point to, it's completely unrelated to the memory you allocate for other pointers in that array. They are in fact 32 *bytes* apart in this case, but that's just pure chance.

In the latter case, you are creating an array of integers which are all bunched together, or "contiguous", in memory. They will be adjacent, hence the pattern you see when you print their addresses, which are 4 *bytes* apart. Evidently, `int` on your system is 4 bytes wide (which is fairly common still).

The "long addresses" are due to your use of dynamic allocation: that'll be the area in virtual memory where your system happens to hold the heap. Nothing to worry about.

So there's nothing "strange" about it.

Comment: Are you sure u did not mix the arrays? By my knowledge, the first one is an array of pointers and the second one is an array of integers. I have not stated that I need them to be contiguous in memory (although they are and in the second case it raises questions) - why only 4 bits between integers (or are they bytes and if so why? )

Comment: @SlowTrout: You're right I flipped them around. But the answer's the same: they are _bytes_ and it's because `int`s are 4 bytes wide on your system.

Answer (score -1):

Int for Array uses 1byte.

Let address of:
 - array[0]=5000

Then
 - array[1]=5001
 - array[2]=5002
 - array[3]=5003
 - array[4]=5004
 - array[5]=5005
 - array[6]=5006
 - array[7]=5007
 - array[8]=5008
 - array[9]=5009

Now, You're assigning pointer.
Then address of Pointer:

- *(array[0])=5010
- *(array[1])=5011
- *(array[2])=5012
- *(array[3])=5013
- *(array[4])=5014
- *(array[5])=5015
- *(array[6])=5016
- *(array[7])=5017
- *(array[8])=5018
- *(array[9])=5019

Here You can easily see that the difference between array[i] and *(array[i]) will be always 10bytes.
**This is because when any Array is called then only it allocates memory total size at once.**

Now addresses of second:
Array arr is defined but not called. **Hence, no memory will be allocated till you call that arr**
**Here, calling is for defining it**

Now, first line says:

```
int arr[10];
```

That only defined the base address.
Then you gave that base address to *start by:

```
int* start=arr;
```

Hence pointer gets that address.
Clearly, Let:
Address of:

- arr[0]=5020
  Then:
- *(start+0)=5020

Since, it is a pointer (not an Array) hence will take 4bytes.
Similarly, all addresses range will be:

- arr[0]=5020 - 5023
- arr[1]=5024- 5028
  And so on..

**Explanation to Allocation:**

- Whenever we define an Array, it defines only the **Base Address**.
  Ex:

  int a[10];

Will allocate base address, i.e., starting address, i.e., address for a[0];

- Whenever you define a pointer, it will also allocate base address only.
- Difference lies only in the allocation, i.e., array allocates 1byte and pointer allocates 4byte (GCC/ Linux/32bit Compiler) for a Pointer.

Comment: If anyone didn't got what I said. Simply understand that all the allocation of address depends on when they are called upon to assign a value. Else only base address is defined.

Comment: There must be some error in explanation of 1st array as I explained that about a 16bit Compiler. Sorry for that.

Comment: But allocation process is same. Only no. Of bytes will differ. So, have attention on Allocation process.

Comment: Sorry but um why? Turbo C is _older than C++_!!! It's over twenty years old and was designed for MS DOS!!!!

Comment: Yes.. You know, I wasn't getting this point to tell.. DOS is the main reason due to which the allocation of memory is like FCFS..